# Has there been a woman that Sanji did not get attracted to?

Tags: one-piece

As far as I have read One Piece, Sanji has not met any woman yet that he did not get attracted to (except okamas, old women and young girls).
My question is, were all middle-aged women in the series supposed to be beautiful? Or does everyone look beautiful to Sanji?

Comment: What about Lola from Thriller Bark Arc? She's a middle-aged woman.

Comment: crocodile (actually did he meet him?)

Comment: @kaine Are you saying that Crocodile is a woman?

Comment: @oshino_shinobu yes but it Is a merely joke about a common fsn theory.   It isnt likely at all.

Comment: I think its kokoro from water 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are women Sanji has met who he hasn't been attracted to, like Kokoro, Lola and Shakuyaku. I believe he's more into young women and young girls, and although he does respect older women, he doesn't swoon over them.

Comment: ^ This. He wanted to die after seeing Kokoro undress, but he would have never ever lay a hand on her if they were to fight.

Comment: old women (aka Kokoro) were explicitly excluded by OP.  Can you confirm Sanji met Lola?  I thought of her but couldn't remember him meeting her.

Comment: I don't recall them talking personally, but I do recall Sanji being in the group when Luffy and co. first met Lola in the woods. And even if I recall incorrectly, all the Straw Hats at the very least met her when they had that party at the end of the arc. Sanji had absolutely no reaction to her (At least none that I remember), which would have not been the case had Lola been a beautiful young woman.